# how do i use pouch db with typescript for cordova applications

Tags: cordova, typescript, pouchdb, angular6

```
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchCdvAdapter from "pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite";
```

importing PouchDb from Nodejs is working

```
var db = new PouchDB('mydb.db', {adapter: 'cordova-sqlite'});
```

Getting error like **PouchDB is not a constructor** for the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions given in [docs](https://pouchdb.com/guides/setup-pouchdb.html#typescript).

1. `npm install pouchdb @types/pouchdb`
2. Add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in  `"compilerOptions"` in your `tsconfig.json`
3. Replace `import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';` with `import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';`

Hope it helps.